# Meteor: Update across all browsers

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working on my first Meteor app, but I can't figure out how I can update something across all browsers.

This is the situation: When one person is typing, I want to display "typing..." across all browsers (so to each user), but I can't figure out how to do that.

This is my code so far:

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");
if( Meteor.isClient ) {

  // Templating
  Template.messages.entries = function() {
    return Messages.find();
  };

  // Events
  Template.messages.events({
    'click #new_post' : function() {
      var new_message = document.getElementById("new_message").value;
      if( new_message.length > 0 ) {
        Messages.insert({ text: new_message });
        document.getElementById("new_message").value = "";
      }
    },
    'focus #new_message' : function() {
      // Say "typing..."
    },
    'blur #new_message' : function() {
      // Say nothing
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see, I want to say: typing when a textfield is focussed. Now I tried this before (but it didn't work out):

```
'focus #new_message' : function() {
  // Say "typing..."
  Template.messages.typing = function() {
    return "typing...";
  };
},
```

But it didn't update my HTML. I got the {{typing}} tag in my template and it's the template messages, so that's right. But it won't update..

You guys have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only Collections are synced across browsers with publish/subscribe in Meteor.

Maybe you can have something like a `Users` collection with an `is_typing` field and create a reactive template helper with it?

Very basic example:

```js
Template.messages.is_typing = function() {
  return Users.find({is_typing:true}).count() > 0
};
```

and in the template

```html
<template name="messages">
  {{#if is_typing}}
     typing
  {{else}}
     idle
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for your answer! But the messages is a collection itself (didn't include that part). So I can't figure out why the typing field is not updated in every browser. Or can an field only be changed if the database changes?

Comment: Hi Andreas, I can't find an other way than yours. So thanks for sharing this and I'm going to try your code. Thanks!